# M2.2.5 Problem with order email

Tags: magento2.2, order-email

Order email was working fine. Now it's not. I don't know what I changed and now it's not working. Only thing I changed in the meantime, was to add a few emails to send the order also.

Other emails are working. Like new customer or change password.

Also Is there a way to check all emails?

Comment: Can you check if its enabled from admin or not?

Comment: Yes it was enabled. However it seems that this was due to [this bug](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14952). I installed this extension https://github.com/sashas777/bug-from-email  now e-mail is send correctly.